# Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1, when writing

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, record

This is my code for adding data to xml:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isstore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
IsolatedStorageFileStream bookfile = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("People.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Open, isstore);

XDocument xmldetails = XDocument.Load(bookfile);
XElement books =
    new XElement("person",
    new XAttribute("id", "5"),
    new XAttribute("name", "Book Title"),
    new XAttribute("beneficiary", "Book Author"),
    new XAttribute("description", "Book Author"),
    new XAttribute("deadline", "Book Author"),
    new XAttribute("price", "Fiction"));
xmldetails.Root.Add(books);

xmldetails.Save(bookfile);
bookfile.Close();
```

This is People.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<people>
    <person index="1" name="Zlecenie numer jeden" beneficiary="Kowalski" description="Proste zlecenie jakiejs strony czy cos" price="800" deadline="27.12.2013" />
</people>
```

When I click button I have this error:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: Post the full error. It's more likely an I/O error than an XML issue.

Comment: I would try removing everything from XElement books = to xmldetails.Root.Add(books);  Your XML in bookfile might have an error when you read it.

Comment: full error name is:
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 4, position 10.

Comment: @ukaszWróblewski: People.xml is invalid.  It is literally that simple.  I'm afraid you might be having a problem expressing *exactly what your issue is* due to the translation.

Comment: @Will: this is my xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<people>
  <person index="1" name="Zlecenie numer jeden" beneficiary="Kowalski" description="Proste zlecenie jakiejs strony czy cos" price="800" deadline="27.12.2013" />
</people>

do you have any ideas to resolve the problem?

Comment: Is this the XML you *expect* to have there or this is the XML that you get if you directly read from file and that's the output? It's completely valid.

Comment: I don't know what is going on. I working on it for 2 - 3 days. Guys please check it on your compilator. You have onclick event and xml file. Tell me if you have some errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your XML file might be missing a root node, and you are trying to add the child node to a non-existent parent. Make sure that your source XML is well-formed.

What you should do, by the way, in your code, is this:

```
XElement books =
            new XElement("person",
            new XAttribute("id", "5"),
            new XAttribute("name", "Book Title"),
            new XAttribute("beneficiary", "Book Author"),
            new XAttribute("description", "Book Author"),
            new XAttribute("deadline", "Book Author"),
            new XAttribute("price", "Fiction"));
xmldetails.Element("People").Add(books);
```

Comment: When I replaced code to yours, I click button and got this message: NullReferenceException at line: xmldetails.Element("People").Add(books);

Comment: I changed name from xmldetails to "plik" and now i've got this: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. Nice :|

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
xmldetails.Root.Add(books);
```

---

`people` is the root of xml so you don't need to specify it..

You should use [Root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root.aspx) property..

Comment: okay, i changed to your proposition. check this:
http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/2263/beztytuusxw.png

Comment: @ŁukaszWróblewski your `xml` file is **invalid**!Show me the xml file content

Comment: check the xml content in your IsolatedStorage